# when taking time.time and time.time away from each other what unit of measurement is the answer in

Tags: python, time

what time frame is time.time in, for example seconds minutes or hours.

When i take time.time and time.time away from each other what unit of measurement is the answer in

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation? https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time

Comment: is it possible to convert the epoch into other units of measurements Joe

Comment: what do you mean by convert the epoch? The epoch is 0 time for the system, so it is always 0. If you want to know what the epoch is, use `print time.ctime(0)`. You might get better answers if you post what you are trying to do and what the expected output is.

Answer (score 1):

The units on `time.time` is seconds.